# Read with pd.read_sqlite a sqlite file in a remote server

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, ssh

Is it possible to read a sqlite3 database that is located in a remote server through ssh in python?
Up to now, I have to copy the file from the server to my local computer and then open it, which is not very efficient...
I am looking for something like this:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
with sqlite3.connect('user@server:path/to/sqlitefile') as conn:
   df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Is it possible to make something like this in Python?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the code from @dan-web (sorry, I don't know how to referr to him) a little bit and now it is working:

```
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sqlite3 /path/to/file.sqlite "select * from table;"')
result = stdout.readlines()
if not result:
    result = stderr.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

You get a list as output. I just converted the list into a Pandas DataFrame... Thanks!

Comment: try this Op, I didnt test mine so this may work!

Answer (score 0):

Use Paramiko

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host=hostname, username='username', password='password')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('sqlite3 
user@server:path/to/sqlitefile "select * from table;"')
stdout=ssh_stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I get an error in the line with ssh.exec_command... The error is: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Can I use then stdout to read the sqlite file with pandas? That was really the problem